# Concatenating String in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know how I would go about concatenating a string in SQL Server 2005.

What I mean is something like the following scenario.

I have a nvarchar(MAX) column in a SQL Server 2005 database.

Lets say the column has a value of "A" and I want to add "B" making "AB", what is the simplest way to go about this. Will I need to do a Select, concatenate the two values in code and then update the column? Or is there a more nifty way to do this?

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In T-SQL:

```
     UPDATE table SET col = col + 'B' WHERE (PREDICATE THAT IDENTIFIES ROW)
```

If you were using Oracle it would be:

```
     UPDATE table SET col = col || 'B' WHERE (PREDICATE THAT IDENTIFIES ROW)
```

Comment: T-SQL is what th OP wanted, see the tags.

Comment: Oracles pipe operators are unique enough that it was worth mentioning for other people who search for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Col VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Col) SELECT 'A'

SELECT  Col + 'B'
FROM    @Table

UPDATE @Table
SET Col = Col + 'B'

SELECT * FROM @Table
```